# How to convert XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue into string?

Tags: ros, roslaunch, yaml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello All,

I am trying to extract topic name as strings from a "yaml" file.
The goal is depicted here:

http://answers.ros.org/question/3289/how-to-write-and-parse-yaml-file-for-ros

I think that I have succeeded to receive the list as XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue class, but I am not succeeding to convert this to a string format.

I have tried to do it in two different ways:

```
    for (int32_t i = 0; i < my_list.size(); ++i) 
    {
        printf ( "Topic %d is: %s.\n", i, static_cast<std::string>(my_list[i]) );
    }

if ( my_list.stringFromXml ( topicsList, &offset ) == TRUE )
{
        printf ("\"topic_list = \"%s", topicsList );
    }
```

The first way doesn´t compiles, and the second doesn´t run...

The two relevant links, I have found, that are connected to this problem are:

1. http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Parameter%20Server
   (roll till the end of the page).
2. http://xmlrpcpp.sourceforge.net/doc/classXmlRpc_1_1XmlRpcValue.html

Both of them doesn´t really help me.

Here is also the code for getting my_list:

```
ros::NodeHandle nh;
XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue my_list;
nh.getParam("topic_list", my_list);
if ( my_list.stringFromXml ( topicsList, &offset ) == TRUE )
{
        printf ("\"topic_list = \"%s", topicsList );
    }
```

While topic_list is the name of the list in "yaml" file:

```
topic_list:
- /bb2/left/image_rect
- /bb2/right/image_rect
```

Thanks in advance,
Felix.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12329/how-to-convert-xmlrpc::xmlrpcvalue-into-string?/) by [Felix Tr](https://answers.ros.org/users/1179/felix-tr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 378 on 2011-12-13

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Tr](https://answers.ros.org/users/1179/felix-tr/) on 2011-12-13**:
See my next post in this page please. Thank you.

**Comment by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) on 2011-12-13**:
What exactly is the compilation error in the first case? Can you also include the code for getting my_list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the main problem is that printf's `%s` formatter expects a C-style string, not a C++ string. All you'd have to do to fix this is:

```
printf ( "Topic %d is: %s.\n", i, static_cast<std::string>(my_list[i]).c_str() );
```

Note the addition of the `.c_str()` function call.

Also, you might want to change `printf` to `ROS_INFO`. All of the formatting is the same, but it has cool ROS functionality.

**EDIT**: Here's a quick explanation. Since `printf` is the output format used in C, not in C++, it expects that you'd be using C-style data structures. The `%s` formatter in C expects that you will pass in a `const char*`, which is C's representation of a string - an array of characters. In C++, however, the `std::string` data structure is more complex than a `const char*` and is its own type entirely. It's essentially the same as trying to use a `double` with `%s`. It's the wrong datatype, and therefore will not work. The `.c_str()` method of a C++ `std::string` returns a `const char*` of the string so that you can use it with C functions.

The block of code `static_cast<std::string>(my_list[i])` returns a `std::string`, and thus you cannot use it with `%s`. `static_cast<std::string>(my_list[i])` is one of C++'s forms of casting `my_list[i]` to an `std::string`. `static_cast<double>(my_list[i])` would cast it to a double.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-12-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Tr](https://answers.ros.org/users/1179/felix-tr/) on 2011-12-14**:
Thanks again :)

**Comment by [Felix Tr](https://answers.ros.org/users/1179/felix-tr/) on 2011-12-14**:
Dmitri, THANKS A LOT for this answer, it works :)!!! I will of course read about it more, but if you have time, can you explain your answer here (decompose into parts). I am writing mostly in C, so I am not sharp enough in C++. Thanks.